# „hergesehen wird“ vs „her gesehen wird“

Tags: verb, preposition, separable-verb

Ich hab vor kurzeum dies hier in einem deutschen Wörterbuch gesehen:

> Passiv |Pạssiv|, das Plural selten
>   Substantiv, Neutrum Sprachwissenschaft
>   das Passiv; Genitiv: des Passivs, Plural: die Passive
>   HERKUNFT lateinisch (genus) passivum
>   Verhaltensrichtung des Verbs, die von der im Satzgegenstand genannten Person oder Sache her gesehen wird, die von einer Handlung betroffen wird; Leideform (z. B. der Hund wird [von Fritz] geschlagen)

Was mich aber besonders interessiert, ist nicht die Definition selber, aber:

> **her gesehen wird**

Sollte es nicht „hergesehen wird“ sein, da das Verb „hersehen” ist? Danke vielmals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nun, dabei handelt es sich um zwei verschiedene Verben mit leicht verschiedenen Bedeutungen.

### Hersehen

Wenn du zu mir hersiehst, dann schaust du in meine Richtung, klarer Fall. Normalerweise würde das wahrscheinlich von Leuten benützt werden, die wollen, dass andere in ihre Richtung schauen.

> General: **Hersehen!**
>
> Lehrerin: Ich wünschte, die Schüler würden öfters hersehen, dann müsste ich nicht alles dreimal erklären.
>
> Spezl in der Bar: Oh, das Mädl, dem du gerade den Drink spendiert hast, hat hergesehen. Deine Chance!

---

### (Von einem Ort) her sehen

Hier ist es plötzlich anders herum. Das *her* gehört nicht mehr zum Verb sondern agiert als eigenes Partikel, meinstens in Kombination mit der Präposition *von.* Man kann es oft durch *aus* ersetzen. Die gedachte Bewegung geht nicht zum Sprecher hin sondern vom Ort der Handlung weg.

> Ich hab gewusst, dass du kommst; ich hab dich vom Turm her gesehen.
>
> Von deinem Standpunkt her gesehen, kann ich wohl nachvollziehen, wie du zu dem Schluss kommst.

---

In keinem Fall ist das gewählte Verb fix; *hersehen* kann durch *herschauen, hergucken* etc. ersetzt werden; In *her sehen* kann man abhängig vom Satzinhalt quasi jedes Beobachtungsverb verwenden *(betrachten, schauen, beobachten, …).* Zusätzlich ist das Partikel *her* in *her sehen* nicht fix, wie schon erwähnt lässt sie sich meistens mindestens durch *aus* ersetzen. Bei *hersehen* ist das nicht der Fall; die einzige Alternative wäre *zu mir sehen.*

Comment: Hint: split compound words at the *Fugen-**s***. Verhalten: acting, Richtung: direction.

Comment: @Jan Danke für Ihre ausgezeichnete Antwort, aber was soll denn „her gesehen wird” in meiner Definition bedeuten? Offensichtlich ist nicht wörtlich gemeint, dass die Verhaltensrichtung des Verbs vom Subjekt betrachtet wird? Soll das etwa bedeuten, dass das Passivteil des Verbs (wird, werden, usw.) sich auf das Subjekt bezieht? Nochmals vielen Dank für Ihre tolle Antwort!

Comment: @user49558 **»Von** der genannten Person her gesehen wird.« Da ist ein von; also wird aus Sicht dieser Person berichtet. Weiter heißt es »die von einer Handlung betroffen wird«, also sie »erleidet«. Wenn ich sage »ich werde geschlagen«, dann ist der Satz aus meinem Blickwinkel (»von mir her«) und ich erleide den Schlag (Passiv).